# Magento 1.9.3.6 - menu Catalog -> Search Terms missing

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.9.3.6

I couldn't find anything about this on Google.

I have to work on search functionality in a Magento site I didn't install.

For some reason the *Catalog -> Search Terms* menu is missing:

Magento 1.9.3.6

Any cue/help?

[image]

EDIT: I found out that I can reach the page from the dashboard. I have to click on any of the *Top 5 Search Terms* and then click on *<- Back*

Anyway the issue is very strange and I didn't find a solution.

Comment: I think the admin user from which you are logged in doesnt have sufficient ACL permissions. Try making a new admin user with all permissions and then login from that user. You can use following link to create a new admin user from database
https://www.atwix.com/magento/reset-admin-password-mysql/

Comment: @surbhiagr, thanks for your help. The user I'm using is an Administrator with all permissions. Anyway I tried what you wrote but unfortunately the problem still remains: no Catalog -> Search Terms menu

Answer (score 0):

That menu point is provided by **CatalogSearch** core module (in app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/etc/adminhtml.xml file)

Assuming you are logged in as an administrator, so you can view all menu points, the first thing I would check would be **System > Configuration > Advanced > Advanced**. You can see there, searching by "Mage_CatalogSearch", if module's output for that module is enabled (it seems it has been disabled)

Other things that could explain your problem: check your project for any 3rd party module rewriting **CatalogSearch** functionality. Maybe some module is hiding that menu point

Last thing (not probable, as I don't think you can disable that module without breaking something), check **CatalogSearch** core module is enabled by browsing **app/etc/modules** xml files

Comment: thanks a lot for you answer. I checked what you wrote: Mage_CatalogSearch module's output is enabled, CatalogSearch core module is enabled in app/etc/modules. Also I looked for anything like _<menu><catalog><children><search>..._ in 3rd party modules but I didn't find anything.

Comment: Any info in Magento logs at var/log folder?

Comment: Lots of these, but don't think they're meaningful: `2019-05-03T07:20:27+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: show_notice  in /app/design/frontend/default/sm_sport/template/page/sm/yt_config_inc.php on line 114
2019-05-03T07:20:28+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: white_border_image  in /app/design/frontend/default/sm_sport/template/hideprice/list.phtml on line 52`

Comment: Also I tried this: I made a new role specifying every single permission including Search Terms and I gave the role to my admin but nothing, even worse because other menu items missing.

Comment: Another try... check app/code/local/Mage folder... maybe a CatalogSearch folder there? If not, and considering the functionality is working, you can always create a local module to recover the menu point, copying the relevant code in app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/etc/adminhtml.xml